# Identity Server 4 Infinite Loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, single-sign-on, identityserver4

I'm working on a asp.net core 2.1 project with identity server 4 installed in it and the users stored in SQL database using entity framework. The Web project has a login page and a dashboard once login is successful.

Please find below the code in Startup.cs,

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(builder =>
            builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, sqlOptions => sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)));

        services.AddDbContext<SingleSignOn_dbContext>(builder =>
            builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "/Master/Login"; // Set the default login page for Identity server.
        }).AddOperationalStore(options =>
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                   builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, sqlOptions => sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)))

            .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                    builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, sqlOptions => sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)))
            .AddAspNetIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Master/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        // Only need to run this once.
        InitializeDbTestData(app);

        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Master}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Client Details below in IDS:

```
 new Client {
                    ClientId = "SingleSignOnInternalClient",
                    ClientName = "Example Implicit Client Application",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                        "role",
                        "customAPI.write"
                    },
                    AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string> {"192.168.6.112"},
                    RedirectUris = new List<string> {"https://localhost:44330/signin-oidc"},  // Configuration.GetSection("TestClient").GetSection("RedirectURL").Value
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string> {"https://localhost:44330"},
                    RequireConsent = false,
                    AllowRememberConsent = false,
                    AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt
                },
```

I've created a client project using asp.net core 2.1 and authorize attribute in the contact page (Home controller).
When we clicked on the contact page, it redirects to the Login page of the other project where identity server is installed and when successful user authorization is made. The page is redirected to an infinite loop.

Startup file of client:

```
 public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

        // Use cooking authentication for signing in users.
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "cookie";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

        })
        .AddCookie("cookie")
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            options.Authority = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Authority:EndPoint");    //services.Configure<"Authority">(Configuration.GetSection("EndPoint"));
            options.ClientId = "SingleSignOnInternalClient";
            options.SignInScheme = "cookie";
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            //options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;    
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        });

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            ///options.Filters.Add

        }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Output Log in Client(infinite redirect Loop):

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:44330/signin-oidc application/x-www-form-urlencoded 1473
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler:Information: AuthenticationScheme: cookie signed in.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 5.4353ms 302 
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:44330/Home/Contact
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Route matched with {action = "Contact", controller = "Home", page = "", area = ""}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult Contact() on controller IdentityTestClient.Controllers.HomeController (IdentityTestClient).
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Information: Authorization failed.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult:Information: Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler:Information: AuthenticationScheme: oidc was challenged.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action IdentityTestClient.Controllers.HomeController.Contact (IdentityTestClient) in 8.3527ms
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 17.5244ms 302

The Url of the infinite loop is below,

> https://localhost:44307/connect/authorize?client_id=SingleSignOnInternalClient&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44330%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=id_token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=636969892902312620.YzUzMWRiNTktN2Q5Mi00NzZiLWJhMjQtNzEzMjI5Mzk1MTE2ZjM5NWQ2NTEtOTQ4Yi00MDljLWIyYzQtNWE5OTA3YWZkMDFj&state=CfDJ8HSRls71XI5DkQoP2L7ypNS9cYyKsLJm7m1dhd3hXQldeb3Esa0g7uZHU6MiqjlsqTk6h7QaqxXsFuMk05KZfdVdN2qJ9j9v5zVg-BeAFNT5rH_Suq8NUl47VUSfTl6zyrBLxYYgeLn8gfdaQpbmwsynpBuMZ9FR8C8eoVNxyPyQ0nGdBryxybey4QFO1xnwiENQtddWxPexgDBNsAGFNd5l6IYhdHaunWz9Ab7NHS68xdfwORdsNFMJRHtUxAGGhQ08U1WP_-TD2xm1rctVfUFZ_GqoNyc_KDanEmp4AVo5eEF0KgQl6mx4kH0PRMPHeDh3KjZTddKEVQglT0J2Kjo&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD1_4&x-client-ver=5.2.0.0

Both the projects have SSL configured to run https locally.

I'm trying to achieve a single sign on solution which has  multiple websites  in different domain and using the Identity server for login.
Any inputs will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cs
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

is not needed client side. 
Beyond the other things, only your IdP should have access to, it re-configures your auth scheme parameters. Anytime you can compare your configuration with the [minimum working one](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/samples/Quickstarts/3_ImplicitFlowAuthentication/src/MvcClient/Startup.cs) from the official repository.

Comment: Right now, working on the sample project [Combined_AspId_and_EFStorage](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/samples/Quickstarts/9_Combined_AspId_and_EFStorage). Result, Identity server project is not starting up (HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure ). When I try to connect using the mvc client getting bad gateway error.

Comment: tried the config mentioned in the link, it didn't work :(  The client configuration mentioned in the question only worked for me. I know there is lot of configuration 
 code which needed to be removed but right now I would like to achieve the desired result b/w client and server.

Comment: Getting the following exception "InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' has been registered." I'm downloaded and working on sample projects from identity server git.

Comment: hard to understand. your messages are too messy. which side, client or server are you talking about? as I understand, initially everything was fine server side, and only client had wrong behavior, right? have you kept your server untouched? then then you have to cleanup related to ASP.Net Identity and IdentityUser client side. that must work.

Comment: Thanks @d-f, it took me some time to understand this middle-ware. After working on couple of sample projects, I've resolved the issues in client and server. Like you mentioned in the answer, the code is not needed and it resolved the problem in the client. There was a _loginPartial shared file added in the client project  whilst initial testing which is used in the Login page which used a `SignInManager<IdentityUser` for authentication(I've to remove it as well). I've also set the RequireConsent option to false in the Client config in Identity server which was the other issue in my case.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was that both apps (IS4 and my api) were using http. After logging in (and leaving that session open in the browser) I moved both apps to SSL. Then the loop began.
My solution was deleting all the cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, removing app.UseHttpsRedirection fixed this for me.